# Deep Zoom in Ajax - Possible? Any examples out there?

Tags: ajax, deepzoom

I have an idea to implement a deep zoom type interface hosted in a browser for sports training data (speed, distance, heart rate etc.) However, rather than images I actually want to zoom into a hierarchy of information. For example, the initial display would contain a grid of years - hover over 2008, for example, and spin the mouse wheel (or click) will zoom into that year but during the zoom I want 2008 to fade out and be replaced with a calendar of months. Again zoom into a month and the months are replaced with the months calendar, zoom into a day and you finally see a chart with the training data plotted on it. All the time only dates with actual data would be highlighted in some fashion.

My question is whether this would even be possible and whether anyone has seen examples of this already. I'm imagining that most of the time the next level of information could be cached in the browser (in fact, because this is calendar-based, I can calculate most of that and cache the dates to be highlighted.) I could also zoom into an empty chart whilst an Ajax thread is fetching the data to display.

I've never tried anything like this before and I'm especially interested in whether DHTML would be capable of this sort of zoom (I suspect not and I would have to resort to Silverlight) and whether the Ajax execution would be uninterrupted whilst the browser rendering thread is kept busy zooming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Deep Zoom on images in JavaScript/Ajax there's the excellent [Seadragon Ajax library](http://livelabs.com/seadragon-ajax/library/) by Microsoft Live Labs.

If you're looking into smooth and interactive zooming on content besides images such as [text](http://gasi.ch/go/openzoom-fte), video & [vectors](http://gasi.ch/blog/openzoom-visualization-z-order/), have a look at the open source [OpenZoom SDK](http://openzoom.org/) I've developed over the last couple of months.

Comment: Not for OpenZoom, but there’s a open source fork of Seadragon Ajax called OpenSeadragon: https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon

Answer (score 2):

You probably could not achieve very smooth zooming with an javascript/ajax type interface, but a zoom interface would be possible. The pragmatic ajax book has a great chapter on implementing a Google maps clone. Theres no need for the technique to be restricted to zooming in and out of tiled images. The image elements can just as easily be any HTML you want. A fade effect could be applied to the zoom operation so when you move up and down a layer you get something similar to what you described. I recommend grabbing the book (Its a pragmatic programmers book, so theres a cheap and immediately downloadable PDF version available. Read the chapter, think about the techniques and then see if you think its practical for your vision. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Seadragon Ajax continues to evolve and is now OpenSeadragon:

http://openseadragon.github.io/

I've also been keeping a list of various zooming technologies, many of which use JavaScript:

https://github.com/iangilman/zooming

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe ajax or dhtml are good solutions for what you are trying to achieve.  I think flash/flex or silverlight may be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "scale" effect in jQuery. [Here's a link.](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Scale) I haven't used it myself, but it might be able to do what you want. You'd have to swap out some content for different content at the right point, or your html would get too big.